# Readfile не работает

Tags: php

Есть такой код:

```
 <?php
$id = basename(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH));
if($id != 'show') {
    require "../../../db.php";
    $db = new mysqli(db_host, db_user, db_pass, db_name);
    if($array_ban = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `adverts` WHERE `id` = '$id'")->fetch_array()) {
       // var_dump($array_ban);
        $file = $array_ban['src'];
        $mime = $array_ban['mime_type'];
        $path = "/var/banners/{$file}";
        if(file_exists($path)) {
         header("Content-Type: " . $mime);
        readfile($path);
        }
        else {
            die("Файл не существует");
        }
    }
}
```

Каталог `/var/banners/` разумеется существует, как и файлы в нем. Права на папке стоят 777. Задача: посредством данного php файла вытащить картинку. Но почему то получаю иконку картинки[image: такую!] , тоесть самой картинки нет. Проверял каждую переменную. Пришел к выводу, что по каким то другим причинам не работает `readfile()`. У меня `nginx+php-fpm`. Если через `alias` вывести эту папку, все работает нормально.
**UPD**: Когда я убираю content-type: %mime% то показывается что то вроде этого [image: http://i.imgur.com/mkHZiOS.png] . А если обратно возвращаю, то пишет Failed to load response data.

Answer (score 1):

Вы забыли `Content-Length`

Вот так правильно

```
$file = 'image.jpg';
$type = 'image/jpeg';
header('Content-Type:'.$type);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
```

Comment: Попробовал, толку 0... `HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Date: Thu, 05 Nov 2015 06:42:24 GMT
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 21164
Connection: keep-alive
`

Comment: Все работает . https://yadi.sk/i/ekUovclnkFcee . Значит у вас проблема в другом. Дайте дебаг всех переменных

Answer (score 0):

Если очень долго не получается, то следует упрощать алгоритм работы скрипта с каждым новым тестированием. Для начала проверить работу примера из документации:

```
<?
$file = __DIR__ . '/test.gif';
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
```

- Удостовериться, что картинка "test.gif" открывается и имеет контент.
- Разместить картинку рядом с файлом скрипта.
- Записать этот пример в отдельный файл скрипта и выполнить прямой запрос к нему из браузера.

Answer (score -1):

Функция `readfile` возвращает количество считанных из файла байт, а не сам файл

Comment: В этом случае, что можно использовать? Если закомментировать отправку content type, то показывается разметка изображения. Что на это скажете?

Comment: @German Mesky Функция записывает файл в буфер вывода, а не то что вы написали